After a fresh installation there are files with error code (1)
Don't know if there is any ask kubuntu forums like this, so I will proceed anyway. I have a Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3 laptop with a Ryzen 5 and a Nvidia 1650. I use Kubuntu 22.04 for a while. Since the last update I am facing issues with the Nvidia drivers. No matter what I kept having issues with the driver, so I decided to perform a fresh installation. Now I am trying to use 24.04 LTS and I got errors. Now, after installing it and running a apt upgrade I got this:
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 apport
 python3-apport
 netplan.io
 python3-pil:amd64
 python3-cryptography
 python3-idna
 update-manager-core
 python3-update-manager
 python3-netplan
 python3-uno
 ubuntu-pro-client
 python3-pkg-resources
 ubuntu-pro-client-l10n
 mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64
 ubuntu-drivers-common
 ubuntu-minimal
 python3-problem-report
 python3-apt
 plasma-distro-release-notifier
 apport-kde
 apport-core-dump-handler
 ufw
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I did a research and I found to perform this:
sudo dpkg --configure -a
and
sudo apt install -f
and
sudo apt remove --purge [package_name]
this "remove" I was unable to run it since it yells that it can be done since python3 is not installed or it can't be deleted.
Also:
sudo apt autoremove and then sudo apt clean.
Also tried:
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/[package_name]
Nothing seems to be working. The system is a fresh installation with nothing but the default packages. Any workaround on this? Any hint on how to solve this issue?

Thanks Mr. @guiverc. Done. I am trying to use 24.04 LTS.

Are you making a fresh install from USB install media? The problems suggest an upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04.

yes @david, a fresh installation from an usb media

This may sound silly but did you run the sequence 'sudo apt-get update' followed by 'sudo apt-get upgrade' ? Both are required and if the the first is not done it will not install correctly.

certainly I did it

I can only suggest downloading the ISO https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/ again and re-install following the instructions. https://userbase.kde.org/Kubuntu/Installation

@david thanks for your comment. Finally I solved the issues first of all I removed python 3 for good and then reinstalled the python 3.12.x, and then I ran apt update and apt upgrade. Next I forced to install the nvidia 550 drivers. Easy to say, but it took more time than expected.
